# How to add an Oracle datasource to Lucee?

Tags: lucee

In Services - Datasource in Lucee admin, there are a short list of types and Oracle isn't one of them.

How can I connect to an Oracle database using Lucee?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the Oracle extension from here
/lucee/admin/server.cfm?action=ext.applications

Oracle will appear in the list of Types after this extension has been added.